# Run code after openid connect sign-in in Asp.net Core

Tags: asp.net-mvc, authentication, .net-core, identityserver3, openid-connect

I am trying to figure out the best way to run some code once a user has authenticated themselves using OpenID Connect on a Dotnet Core MVC App. I don't want to hard code a redirect URL after sign-in because they still need to end up where they were trying to get to after authentication.  I just need to run code eg. "check if its the first time sign-in and set a flag" or something similar.

I was using a middle-ware but since this gets called for every request its causing some problems.

Does anyone have any ideas on how to achieve this?

Comment: How did you go with this? I have exactly the same requirement but haven't been able to come up with a suitable solution yet. I posted a similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45618386/how-to-redirect-after-azure-ad-authentication-to-different-controller-action-in)

Comment: How did you solve the problem? I have the exact same issue.

Comment: You should have a method which generates your api token... just call a method in there once the authentication process is complete and have a flag in the users table like AccountNeverLoggedIn...

Comment: @TejSoft Currently what I am doing is using a middleware to check if a account_created claim is set in the claims principle of the logged in user. If not then I know its a first time login then create the claim for the user. Since the check has no IO, just checks the token, there is no cost really for doing it this way.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I am using OpenIdConnect events to solve this problem.

```
.AddOpenIdConnect("oidc", options =>
{
   options.Events = new OpenIdConnectEvents
   {
       OnTokenValidated = async ctx =>
       {
           var userID = ctx.Principal.FindFirstValue("sub");

           var db = ctx.HttpContext.RequestServices.GetRequiredService<MyDb>();

           //Do things I need to do with the user here.

       }
   }
}
```

Comment: This runs *every* time the user submits a token, not every time they actually sign in and get said token. If that's a problem for you, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49691132/2630078).

Comment: That is definitely a better solution for my original requirement thanks. However now I am also adding claims to the principle on the token so I need it every time a new token is obtained through the back channel.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this type of selective re-routing should be performed within an class inheriting from `AuthorizeAttribute`;  Many preamble actions can be taken in there, including applying additional Role contexts.

One example is reading and accepting Terms and Conditions, which must be performed once for a login credential (read User).  This can be performed by a redirect to lower-role protected MVC Controller. Once accepted the Role "`TandC_Consent`" (or whatever other role) can be applied to the user, and the user can be re-directed to a controller which validates using `[AuthorizePermission("TandC_Consent")]` every time afterwards.

[This github example](https://github.com/auth0-samples/auth0-roles-permissions-dashboard-sample/wiki/Example:-Adding-authorization-to-an-ASP.NET-MVC-web-application) shows how to implement the `AuthorizeAttribute` instance and the `[AuthorizePermission()]` decorator.

Answer (score -1):

I was also searching how to do it and I finally I used IdentityServer3. There is IUserService interface which defines some methods you can overload. One of these method is `PostAuthenticateAsync` From IdentityServer3 documentation:

> This method is called after the user has successfully authenticated
>   but before they are returned to the client application. It allows a
>   consolidated place to check for custom user workflows after all of the
>   other authentication methods. It’s designed for UI workflows. Passed a
>   PostAuthenticationContext with these properties: SignInMessage: The
>   contextual information passed to the authorize endpoint.
>   AuthenticateResult: The current AuthenticateResult. The user service
>   can re-assign to a non-null value to change the authentication
>   outcome.

The `context` parameter has `AuthenticateResult` property which can be set to a custom authentication result:

```
public override Task PostAuthenticateAsync(PostAuthenticationContext context)
{
    // code that will determine target url
    // redirectPath = ...
    context.AuthenticateResult = AuthenticateResult(redirectPath, claims);
}
```

redirectPath must start with / or ~/"

Here is an [example](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer3.AspNetIdentity/blob/master/source/IdentityServer3.AspNetIdentity/IdentityServer3.AspNetIdentity.cs) of `IUSerService` implementation.

Comment: This is for the identity server itself but the requirement is for the client application.