# Handling callback from Identity Server

Tags: oauth, oauth-2.0, identityserver4, openid, asp.net-core-3.1

As a client app, user logged in from Identity server and redirected to `/signin-oidc` endpoint the the client app. `/signin-oidc` is handled automatically by OpenId middleware already so i can not put my registration user process at first login.

On external login process in the case of Google, Facebook or Microsoft, there was a `returnUrl` redirection at the end of successful login and i was able to inject my registration(saving user details)  code logic.

It seems OpenId is different on this aspect. So what is right way to registration process ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use notification events in OIDC OWIN Middlerware which invokes to enable developer add custom logic . For example, you can query the database and create a user in `OnTokenValidated` event :

```
options.Events = new OpenIdConnectEvents
{
    OnTokenValidated = ctx =>
    {
        //query the database 

        var db = ctx.HttpContext.RequestServices.GetRequiredService<YourDbContext>();

        //perform custom logic for user management in local database


        return Task.CompletedTask;
    },
};
```

Comment: I wouldn't like to access service locator so i my preference would be handle it inside controller but i guess this is only way to do that.

Comment: If you want do that in controller , you can manually set the path : `if (!User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
{
    return Challenge(new AuthenticationProperties() { RedirectUri = "/home/redirectOnRole" } , AzureADDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
}` , see https://stackoverflow.com/a/61452853/5751404 . Change scheme name based on your authentication scheme

Comment: Or you can do that in index page ,  since by default , the oidc middleware will back to index page after authentication .