# How to redirect to the original path user navigated to after AAD authentication?

Tags: asp.net-core, azure-active-directory

I have a pretty straightforward ASP .NET Core web site that uses Azure AD + OpenID for user authentication. Inside Azure I've added "https://my-site/signin-oidc" as a Redirect URI and inside my app settings I've set my CallbackPath to "/signin-oidc".

The problem is after authentication the browser always redirects to the home page.

For example the user will enter the following url into their address bar:
`https://my-site/#/foo`

They'll then be redirected to the azure sign-in page which has a uri like so:
`https://login.microsoftonline.com/.../oauth2/v2.0/authorize?client_id=...&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fmy-site%3A64199%2Fsignin-oidc&[...]&sso_reload=true#/foo=`

(Note where the '#/foo' fragment is placed)

After authentication succeeds they end up at the home page (`https://my-site/`).

Is there anyway for me to preserve the original URI and redirect the user to it after auth succeeds?

Comment: I think this [official document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/reply-url#use-a-state-parameter) can answer your question.

Comment: I also find [another solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45670664) here, which means you can redirect to a business center page, in which you can check if the user already signed in then write your own business to redirect the application to your target page.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the **post_login_redirect_url** query parameter for this.

If you want to automatically navigate the user to #/foo' after logging in, you can set your login redirect to ~/.../authorize?post_login_redirect_url=/#/foo.